# MongoDB dynamic update of collection when changes occurs in another collection

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver

I created two collections using Robomongo :
  collection_Project that contains documents like this

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5537ba643a45781cc8912d8f"),

"_Name" : "ProjectName",
"_Guid" : LUUID("16cf098a-fead-9d44-9dc9-f0bf7fb5b60f"),
"_Obj" : [ 
 ]
}
```

that I create with the function

```
public static void CreateProject(string ProjectName)
    {
        MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost/TestCreationMongo");
        var db = client.GetServer().GetDatabase("TestMongo");
        var collection = db.GetCollection("collection_Project");
        var project = new Project
        {
            _Name = ProjectName,
            _Guid = Guid.NewGuid(),
            _Obj = new List<c_Object>()
        };
        collection.Insert(project);
    }
```

and collection_Object that contains documents like this

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5537ba6c3a45781cc8912d90"),
  "AssociatedProject" : "ProjectName",
  "_Guid" : LUUID("d0a5565d-a0aa-7a4a-9683-b86f1c1de188"),
  "First" : 42,
  "Second" : 1000
}
```

That I create with the function

```
 public static void CreateObject(c_Object ToAdd)
    {
        MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost/TestCreationMongo");
        var db = client.GetServer().GetDatabase("TestMongo");
        var collection = db.GetCollection("collection_Object");

        collection.Insert(ToAdd);
```

I update the documents of collection_Project with the function

```
 public static void AddObjToProject(c_Object ObjToAdd, string AssociatedProject)
    {
        MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost/TestCreationMongo");
        var db = client.GetServer().GetDatabase("TestMongo");
        var collection = db.GetCollection<Project>("collection_Project");

        var query = Query.EQ("_Name", AssociatedProject);
        var update = Update.AddToSetWrapped<c_Object>("_Obj", ObjToAdd);

        collection.Update(query, update);
    }
```

so that the documents in collection_Project look like this

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5537ba643a45781cc8912d8f"),
"_Name" : "ProjectName",
"_Guid" : LUUID("16cf098a-fead-9d44-9dc9-f0bf7fb5b60f"),
"_Obj" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5537ba6c3a45781cc8912d90"),
        "AssociatedProject" : "ProjectName",
        "_Guid" : LUUID("d0a5565d-a0aa-7a4a-9683-b86f1c1de188"),
        "First" : 42,
        "Second" : 1000
    }
  ]
}
```

Can I update the document only in the collection_Object and see the change in the collection_Project as well ?

I tried to do that

```
 public static void UpdateObject(c_Object ToUpdate)
    {
        MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost/TestCreationMongo");
        var db = client.GetServer().GetDatabase("TestMongo");
        var collection = db.GetCollection("collection_Object");

        var query = Query.EQ("_Guid", ToUpdate._Guid);
        var update = Update.Replace<c_Object>(ToUpdate);
        collection.Update(query, update);
    }
```

but I the collection_Project doesn't change.

Do you have any clue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are embedding the 'Object' document inside the 'Project' document, which might be fine, but that approach eliminates the need for your separate collection_Object collection. That is to say, collection_Object is redundant because each object (not just a reference) is actually stored inside the Project document as you have implemented it.

See the documentation for information on using [embedded documents](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/).

Alternatively, you could use [document references](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/).

The best approach to use depends on your specific use case.